# What predictive model is appropriate?

Tags: predictive-models, prediction

I am trying to forecast the number of bikes (or empty stands) available at a station in a bike sharing system. For example: I would like to know how many bikes should be available at a given station next Monday, between 8 and 8.05am .

Data used:

- History of available bikes/stand per station recorded every minute
- Weather conditions (dry / wet)

[image]

I found out that chances of getting a bike were 20% higher on a wet day.

So basically, I'd like a model which can use these factors to estimate the number of bikes that should be there, based on :

- historical data of this station for this day of the week and this time of the day
- dry/wet weather

I've been advised to use Logistic Regression, but I am wondering if the output of it will be binary or if it can be an actual number of bikes ? Apologies in advance for my poor maths level, but I would definitely enjoy a bit of help, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Logistic regression may potentially not be of much help here. I can guess why it was suggested but there's a good chance that won't be appropriate for such a scenario. This is a time series problem and you need to use a time series technique, preferably one with external regressors such as ARIMAX, regression with ARMA errors, or neural network autoregression (just to name a few). If you're using R, you can find most of these in package 'forecast'.

Comment: It's *possible* a regression-type model may suffice (there may only be weak autocorrelation type effects), so I'd hesitate to say "won't help at all" (and further, while modelling the count of number available would generally be better than just modelling available/unavailable, such a model would still carry some information). Certainly the issues you raise are important and should certainly be considered because it would be reasonably unusual for there to be no serial-dependence worth worrying about.

Comment: I can see why GLM was suggested here but since the word _forecast_ was used I assumed that autocorrelation would be very high (I have anyway edited my answer to reflect the points you raised).